# Input value doesn't save in variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
      <form>
        <label for="">Number Of bars</label>
        <br />
        <input type="number" id="num" value="" />
        <button type="button" onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </form>


function onSubmit(){
const num=document.getElementById("num").value;
return Number(num);}
const numberOfBar= onSubmit();
```

I need **this input value** to use in other **function**

Comment: parse it to your other function `function anotherFunction(num);`  in your onSubmit

Comment: Call that function directly. You will get the value from id in any function.

Comment: @ShoryaVaish I did it but won't work, can other function effects it?

Comment: Can you show here what are you trying to achieve and how called that function?

Comment: @Alex Still not get the return value, can please elaborate for me whats the output looks like?

Comment: @ShoryaVaish ```function onSubmit(){
    const num=parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
    return num;
}

const numberOfBar=onSubmit();
console.log("No of Bars", numberOfBar);
const barWidth=  300/numberOfBar;```

Comment: Calculate width inside onSubmit()

Comment: @ShoryaVaish It failed? I don't know why this happing again and again, still fail.

Comment: Is there anyhow other function or method impacts it?

Comment: @Alex from input value, ``` barWidth=  300/numberOfBar;```  I want to do this and then this bar width will be added to ```  createBar.style.width=barWidth+'px';```

Comment: @Alex I did this but still not get the output as required.

Comment: createBar.style.width=\`${barWidth}px\` the value have to be in apostrophe

Comment: It is so frustrating looking very simple but don't know why it is not working...

Comment: can you update your question with the new informations and with this createBar.style.width part?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite as follows:

```
<form>
        <label for="">Number Of bars</label>
        <br />
        <input type="number" id="num" value="" />
        <button type="button">Submit</button>
      </form>

function otherFunction(){
//This should be able to get the value as long the state is preserved.
const num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);

}
```

Comment: I did this also still failed.

Comment: from input value, ``` barWidth= 300/numberOfBar;``` I want to do this and then this bar width will be added to ``` createBar.style.width=barWidth+'px';```

Answer (score 0):

should be straightforward to do this

```js
let numberOfBar = null;

function onSubmit() {
  numberOfBar = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value, 10);
  console.log(numberOfBar);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="">Number Of bars</label>
  <br />
  <input type="number" id="num" value="" />
  <button type="button" onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I already did this also, till console works fine but when the time to get the real value it faild whole function. I don't know why this happening?

Comment: sorry, can you please elaborate on what is failing? when does it happen?

Comment: ```const barWidth=  300/numberOfBar;
const style=document.createElement('style');
const bars=displayBars();
const barArray=Array.from   (bars.querySelectorAll('div'));```

Comment: from input value, ``` barWidth= 300/numberOfBar;``` I want to do this and then this bar width will be added to ``` createBar.style.width=barWidth+'px';```

Comment: maybe it is easy for you to create a new question, and use jsfiddle.net to provide a simple example. As you can see that it is difficult to provide code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numberOfBar= 0;
function onSubmit(){
    const num=document.getElementById("num").value;
    numberOfBar= num;
}

function showResult(){
    alert(numberOfBar);
}
```

```html
          <form>
            <label for="">Number Of bars</label>
            <br />
            <input type="number" id="num" value="" />
            <button type="button" onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="showResult()">Show Number of Bars</button>
          </form>
```

This should work!